# CLion code completion for CUDA missing some functions

Tags: cuda, clion

I'm using CLion with Cuda toolkit on Windows 11 with MSVC compiler. It works and compiles fine, but the code completion is missing a lot of items like `cudaMalloc` and `cudaFree`. It *does* include *some* items though, like CudaMemAttachGlobal, see screenshot below.

I think it's because I haven't included any headers, but nvcc doesn't require explicit inclusion of headers, and the default CMake settings in CLion compiles and runs my .cu files just fine.

Is there anything extra I'm supposed to do to get CLion code completion to look at the entire available API from nvcc?

EDIT: The above description was with cuda toolkit on windows with MSVC. Now I tried it with cuda toolkit from the Nvidia installations instructions on Fedora 35, and the symptoms are exactly the same. The completion items are only macros, no actual functions. I looked through `cuda_runtime_api.h` and the signature for cudaFree is

`extern __host__ __cudart_builtin__ cudaError_t CUDARTAPI cudaFree(void *devPtr);`

[image]

Comment: Are sure they really are not there if you scroll?

Comment: they are not there. If I type cudaMal for example, the number of items in that menu go down to zero.

Comment: Ok. Those are all types and preprocessor definitions it is pulling up. There are no API  calls I can see, meaning it isn’t searching all the CUDA runtime API headers, only some of them. You could try adding some includes and see what happens

Comment: so after I typed `cudaFree`, I hovered over it and it gave me the signature and told me it's "from cuda_runtime_api.h", so I included that header, and the code completion STILL didn't include cudaFree.

Out of curiosity, does code completion work on those functions work in *your* instance of CLion?

Comment: I don’t use CLion, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

It seems if I press Ctrl+Space, then the code completion menu works perfectly, and is able to complete both CudaMalloc and CudaFree, and anything else. If I don't press Ctrl+Space and just let it show the menu, it still shows the menu but only has macros in it.

Without ctrl+space:

[image: without ctrl+space shows just macros]

With ctrl+space:

[image: with ctrl+space works perfectly]

Original:

This seems to be a bug in either CLion or whatever subroutine (maybe CMake) it calls to get the code completions from header files; I tried this on Fedora Linux and observed the exact same behavior.

In contrast, VSCode has an NSight plugin that's developed by Nvidia, and that is able to code-complete functions like cudaMallocManaged and cudaFree with no problems.